# ADO.NET ExecuteReader Returns No Results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I'm updating some old legacy code and I ran into a problem with the
SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() method. The problem is that it's not returning any
results. However, using SqlDataAdapter.Fill(), I get results back from the
database. What am I doing wrong? How can I get results back using the data
reader?

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString();

using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1";
        sqlConnection.Open();

        // This code works.
        //var dataTable = new DataTable();
        //using (var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
        //{
        //  sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        //}

        // This code is not working.
        using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                // This fails because the data reader has no results.
                var id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `sqlDataReader.GetValue(0)` ? Does that return data ?

Comment: What exactly fails - what is error message?

Comment: Is the first field an int? can you post the data retrieved by the query? There must be data at that row, but the question is, what does it look like?

Comment: The first field is a non-nullable integer and is the primary key, the second and third fields are non-nullable decimal types. The GetValue(0) method works. That's odd that GetInt32(0) doesn't.

Comment: IF GetValue(0) works then it is not failing for no result.  What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that there is no `Int32` in your results ?

```
var id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0); // <-- this might not be an Int32
```

Either try:

```
var id = sqlDataReader.GetValue(0);
```

Or cast to the correct type (`BIGINT` for example is `Int64`), not sure without seeing your data.

Comment: The column in the table is (PK, int, not null), so GetInt32 should work. GetValue works, but I have to cast it to an integer.

Comment: @Halcyon Casting to an `int` is not the same as calling `GetInt32()` it won't work if it's not an exact type match where casting a short to an int is ok. Does `GetInt32()`  throw an exception when you call it ?

Comment: There was an error thrown, so you are exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

If you got to that line then it has results
Does not mean the value is not null
And you should not use a SELECT *
If may have a problem with an implicit cast
Try Int32

```
try
{
    if(sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
       // deal with null
    }
    else  
    {
      Int32 id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
catch (SQLexception Ex) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Ex.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
var id = 0;

using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(sqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("ColName"));
            }
        }
```

I have moved the variable outside of the reader code or the variable will only be accessible inside that scope.  I would avoid specifying the ordinal in the code, in case someone altered the columns in the DB.

Also, specify the columns in the **SQL** statement... `SELECT ColName FROM ...` and use [*params*](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) in the query

Answer (score -2):

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString();

using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1";

    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection))
    {
        using (var sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                // This fails because the data reader has no results.
                var id = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference here?

Comment: opened connection is passed to SQLCommand, this code works 100%, so since original code doesn't trap any exception i assume first column is not an integer, in general its a bad practice to do select *

Comment: The OP is already doing that, `sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;` & `sqlConnection.Open();`

Comment: then it fails because of conversion to int.

Comment: All that matter is that the connection is opened before the execute

Comment: I'm just saying the answer you have given is essentially the same code that the OP is having an issue with... I didn't -1 though!

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the actual problem here. I recommend reading more closely before answering.